# Location of customers details in the database

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

In a Wordpress site with Woocomerce, how do I find out which database holds the customers details please?  Looking in phpMyAdmin, there seems to be six DB's there?

Answer (score 1):

You can see the customer details in ( It holds normal user )

```
wp_user
wp_usermeta
```

Tables

and customer related information of woo commerce you can get it on

```
wp_postmeta
```

Table

[image]

Comment: Thanks, how do I do a query to list the details please?